# PostgreSQL - Создание таблицы и вставка данных в таблицу с ограничением CHECK

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Имеется некая таблица, в которой есть поля с ограничением CHECK. Возникает проблема при добавлении данных в таблицу с помощью INSERT INTO.

В чём может быть проблема?

```
CREATE TABLE car.tCar(
Car_Number1_PK char(3) NOT NULL CHECK(Car_Numbere1_PK LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]') PRIMARY KEY,
Car_Number2 char(3) NOT NULL CHECK(Car_Number2 LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'),
First_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Last_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO car.tCar(Car_Number1_PK, Car_Number2, First_Name, Last_Name)
VALUES('123', 'ABC', 'Ivan', 'Ivanov');
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> ERROR:  new row for relation "tcar" violates check constraint "tcar_car_number1_pk_check"
>       DETAIL:  Failing row contains (123, ABC ,Ivan, Ivanov).

Comment: Имя столбца в CHECK написано с ошибкой.

Comment: like не понимает регулярных выражений, используйте операторы сравнения по маске.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
...
CHECK(Car_Numbere1_PK ~* '^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$'),
CHECK(Car_Number2 ~* '^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$')
...
```

или

```
...
CHECK(Car_Numbere1_PK ~* '^[0-9]{3}$'),
CHECK(Car_Number2 ~* '^[A-Z]{3}$')
...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Ваш ответ помог мне! Проблема решилась. Значит оператор LIKE подходит только для сравнения с шаблоном. Ешё раз спасибо!

Comment: @VasilisaIvanova, да, `LIKE` не работает с RegEx'ами, вернее он их воспринимает буквально, как соответствующую строку...